# How to integrate dashboard on exsiting app with ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, frontend, react-router-dom, reactify

I have a dashboard [Reactify](https://themeforest.net/item/reactify-reactjs-redux-material-bootstrap-4-admin-template/20922934) and I want to integrate it into my reactjs app with create-react-app.

I want to redirect to the dashboard from my application with the route `/admin`.

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i hope you are using 'react-router-dom' package for routing. if yes, you can import your dashboard component and use it inside the Router tag to route to the dashboard.

for example:

```
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard.js'; //give proper path to dashboard      component
//then inside render in your app
render() {
return (
<Router>
<Route path="/admin" component={Dashboard} />
</Router>"    
);
}
```

to learn the basics, checkout the documentation for
[react-router-dom](https://redux.js.org/advanced/usage-with-react-router)

Hope this would be helpful!